# Transpose colums to rows for each unique value in Excel

Tags: excel, transpose

I have data in a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
B 3
B 4
C 1
C 2
```

I want it to be like this:

```
A 1 2 3 *
B 1 2 3 4
C 1 2 * *
```

where each letter or number is in a seperate cell. The `*` indicates an empty cell.

I've started copying and pasting and checking 'transpose' in the paste special dialogue but had to give up because the spreadsheet is just too large to do it manually. I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962828/excel-transpose-some-rows-into-columns-depending-on-values-in-another-column) but it doesn't exactly fit my needs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a PivotTable with labels (say Letter and Number) where Letter is in Row Labels, Number is in Column Labels and Sum of Number for Σ Values?